# Google AdWords Conversion Tracking (Page Refresh Effect)

Tags: google-ads-api

I copied and pasted the Google AdWords conversion tracking code generated from Google AdWords onto my order confirmation page:

```
<!-- Google Code for Sale Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 0123456789;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "V772CLqB........";
var google_conversion_value = {{total}};
if ({{total}}) {
  google_conversion_value = {{total}};
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{protocol}}://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="{{protocol}}://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/0123456789/?value={{total}}&amp;label=V772CLqB........&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

For the conversion count (1-per-click) what happens when the user refreshes the page? Does the count increase by 1 again?

I understand that for the conversion count (many-per-click) when the user refreshes the page. The count increases by 1 again.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Cappucino, have you figured it out yet? Would be great if you could tell. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-per-click conversions will only count 1 conversion per user no matter how many times they refresh the page.

You can read the official documentation here:
http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6365

"This type is useful for measuring conversions that count once per customer such as leads or sign-ups."